# Create new Tab with the correct values displayed in the TabBarView

Tags: flutter, dart

This Flutter code connects to an ESP32 via WebSocket and displays data received from the device. The app has a TabBar that allows the to switch between different connected ESP32 devices. I can add new ESP32 devices by opening an "Add Station" dialog where i can enter the device's name, IP address, and port. When i add a new device, a new tab is created for that device and the app connects to the device via the WebSocket using the provided IP address and port.
I can also remove any added device.
The problem that i have is that when i add a new device a new tab is created but the name of the ESP32, the values and the reconnect button are not displayed in the TabBarView.

I would need some help on this. I do not see what i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for some help.

Follows the code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'ESP3" Monitor',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class Station {
  late final String name;
  late final String ipAddress;
  late final String port;
  double rangeData;
  double forceData;

  Station({
    required this.name,
    required this.ipAddress,
    required this.port,
    this.rangeData = 0.0,
    this.forceData = 0.0,
  });
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final List<Station> _stations = [];
  late TabController _tabController;
  late IOWebSocketChannel _channel;
  late TextEditingController _stationName;
  late TextEditingController _ipAddress;
  late TextEditingController _port;
  String? selectedTab = tabs[0].text;
  var tabName = "";

  static List<Tab> tabs = [
    const Tab(text: ""),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _stationName = TextEditingController();
    _ipAddress = TextEditingController();
    _port = TextEditingController();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: tabs.length);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _stationName.dispose();
    _ipAddress.dispose();
    _port.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _connectToEsp32(String ipAddress, String port, Station station) {
    _channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://$ipAddress:$port');
    _channel.stream.listen(
      (data) {
        final Map<String, dynamic> receivedData = jsonDecode(data);
        setState(() {
          final int index = _stations.indexWhere((element) => element.name == station.name);
          if (index >= 0) {
            station.rangeData = receivedData['range'];
            station.forceData = receivedData['force'];
            _tabController.animateTo(index);
          }
        });
      },
    );
  }

  void _openAddStationDialog(BuildContext context) {
    _stationName.text = "";
    _ipAddress.text = "";
    _port.text = "";
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Add Station'),
          content: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.list),
                    labelText: 'Station Name',
                  ),
                  controller: _stationName,
                  validator: (value) {
                    tabName = value!;
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter a Station Name';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.computer),
                    labelText: 'IP Address',
                  ),
                  controller: _ipAddress,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter IP address';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.settings_applications),
                    labelText: 'Port',
                  ),
                  controller: _port,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter Port';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {});
                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  final station = Station(
                    name: _stationName.text,
                    ipAddress: _ipAddress.text,
                    port: _port.text,
                  );
                  _stations.add(station);
                  tabs.add(Tab(text: tabName));
                  _connectToEsp32(station.ipAddress, station.port, station);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.add,
              ),
              label: const Text('Add'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: tabs.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Station Monitor'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {
                _openAddStationDialog(context);
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.keyboard_control_rounded,
              ),
              label: const Text('Add Station'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      title: const Text("Select tab to remove"),
                      content: tabs.isNotEmpty
                          ? StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                              return DropdownButton<String>(
                                items: tabs.map((tab) {
                                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: tab.text,
                                    child: Text(tab.text ?? ""),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                                onChanged: (String? value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    selectedTab = value;
                                  });
                                },
                                value: selectedTab,
                              );
                            })
                          : Container(),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        ElevatedButton(
                          child: const Text("Remove"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (tabs.isNotEmpty) {
                              setState(() {
                                int index = tabs.indexWhere((tab) => tab.text == selectedTab);
                                tabs.removeAt(index);
                                selectedTab = tabs.isNotEmpty ? tabs[0].text : null;
                              });
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
              label: const Text('Remove Station'),
            ),
          ],
          bottom: TabBar(tabs: tabs),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: _stations.map((station) {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(children: <Widget>[
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Station Name: ${station.name}"),
                      const SizedBox(width: 10),
                      PopupMenuButton<int>(
                        itemBuilder: (context) => [
                          const PopupMenuItem(
                            value: 1,
                            child: Text("Reconnect"),
                          ),
                        ],
                        onSelected: (value) {
                          if (value == 1) {
                            _connectToEsp32(station.ipAddress, station.port, station);
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ]),
                Text("Range: ${station.rangeData}"),
                Text("Force: ${station.forceData}"),
              ],
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TabController`s are a bit tricky to rebuild (or rather to change the state of it), so one of the solutions is to update its key when you need to rebuild it (its state).
Here is the full working example on how to add a new tab programmatically, so you can adjust it to your needs:

```
class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  const Sample({super.key});

  @override
  State<Sample> createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  final List<Tab> tabs = [Tab(text: "Tab 1"), Tab(text: "Tab 2")];
  var tabControllerKey = GlobalKey();

  void _openAddTabDialog() {
    final tabNameController = TextEditingController();
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Add Tab'),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: tabNameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Tab Name'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          actions: [
            ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  tabs.add(Tab(text: tabNameController.text));
                  // this is needed for the tab controller to update
                  tabControllerKey = GlobalKey();
                });
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              label: const Text('Add'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      key: tabControllerKey,
      length: tabs.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Dynamic Tabs'),
          actions: [
            ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: _openAddTabDialog,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              label: const Text('Add Tab'),
            ),
          ],
          bottom: TabBar(tabs: tabs),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: TabBarView(children: tabs),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Some similar code i used to create my Dynamic Tabs in my code.

Comment: That's ok, all that matters is that you found a solution that works for you 

Comment: Thanks for your help. Some similar code i used to create my Dynamic Tabs in my code. But unfortunately i am not able to create the correct code (logic) to display correctly all values inside the TabBarView after i create some new Tabs. The values that are displayed are always the ones that i introduced when i create the first Tab. That means that in Tab3 and Tab4 and Tab5 are displayed the values who belongs to Tap1